# What are all the things you need for a provisional patent application?

Tags: provisional, new

I am new to the patenting world, and I am a little confused about how to go about drafting a provisional patent application. How in depth do I need to be about my idea? Do I need supplemental drawings, and if so, how detailed, and how many?

Overall, I just need an idea of how to start. What are some things to get me on the right path?

There was mention of a possible duplicate on this question, but the other question had to do with web or app development. Mine is purely mechanical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How detailed should a provisional patent application be? (Software)](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/how-detailed-should-a-provisional-patent-application-be-software)

Comment: The subject matter makes no difference. The law for software inventions is the same as the law for mechanical inventions (at least, for the purposes of the requirements of a provisional patent application). That is why I believe this is a duplicate. However, if you think I'm glossing over something important, please do highlight what that is, since that could lead to quite a good question (and more helpful answers for you).

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read below a provisional patent should have a complete description of the invention.  If it does not then it can be used against you to show that you did not have an invention.

http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2013/10/19/good-bad-ugly-truth-about-provisional-patent-applications-2/id=45766/

http://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/patent-basics/types-patent-applications/provisional-application-patent

http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s601.html

Not intended as legal advice.  Please upvote or check as answered if this satisfies you.